# Round-robining among consumers not working?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm trying to modify my spring-amqp project such that if a certain exception type is thrown, always requeue the message.  Otherwise, retry x number of times then reject.

Here is the relevant configuration xml

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitMqConnectionFactory" host="localhost" port="5672" />

<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitMqConnectionFactory"
    exchange="my.exchange" routing-key="foo"/>

<bean id="myListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitMqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="2" />
    <property name="queueNames" value="work.q" />
    <property name="adviceChain" ref="myRetryInterceptor" />
</bean>
```

And here is the relevant code

```
 @Bean(name="myRetryInterceptor")
public MethodInterceptor getInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
        .retryPolicy(getRetryPolicy())
        .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
        .build();
}

private RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {      
    return new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, Collections.EMPTY_MAP) {
        @Override
        public boolean canRetry(RetryContext context) {
            Throwable t = context.getLastThrowable();
            if ((t!=null) && (t.getCause() instanceof com.test.MessageRetryException)) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.canRetry(context);
        }
    };
}
```

I notice that when I deliberately throw a com.test.MessageRetryException in myMessageListener, the same thread is given the message over and over again.  This is in contrast to an implementation where no spring classes are modified.  In this case, the message is given alternately to one consumer thread then another.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
@Bean(name="myRetryInterceptor")
//all consumers are given the message here
public MethodInterceptor getInterceptor() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No; you're doing nothing wrong; stateless retry is done within the scope of the original delivery (on the same thread). Message rejection does not occur until the retries are exhausted.

Stateful retry, on the other hand, rejects the delivery on each attempt and it will be resubmitted and (possibly) handled by a different thread.

Since rabbitmq now requeues rejected message at the head of the queue, there is not really any benefit of switching to stateful recovery and it requires a message id header to work (so the state can be determined for the message).

**EDIT**: Hmmm - I see you are using stateful retry; so I would expect the redeliveries to happen on alternate threads.

If you can post a DEBUG log on a Gist or some place; I can take a look. But, as I said, stateless retry is simpler anyway.

Comment: Re your edit: In the second code block the OP uses stateless retries.  When he uses stateful retries (third block) they get distributed in round-robin fashion as expected.